# Flutter build ios --release me lanza error

Tags: flutter, xcode, build

una consulta estava trabajando normalmente en vscode ya fueron varias veces que he hecho entre

```
flutter clean
flutter build ios --release
```

y siempre era todo ok me generaba el build luego iva al xcode y seleccionaba product-archive y listo todo ok.

Pero derrepente de un rato a otro no se q paso parece que de tanto generar los comandos mencionados arriba se frego o no se que pasaria. pero ahora a la hora de realizar el comando:

```
flutter build ios --release
```

me lanza este erro en la consola.

```
Xcode build done.                                           46.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
In file included from
/Users/admin/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter- 
0.3.22+1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:5:
/Users/admin/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter- 
0.3.22+1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.h:12:
40: error: expected a type
- (instancetype)initWithMethodChannel:(FlutterMethodChannel*)methodChannel
                                       ^
/Users/admin/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter- 
0.3.22+1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:8:3
: error: unknown type name 'FlutterMethodChannel'
  FlutterMethodChannel* _methodChannel;
  ^
/Users/admin/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter- 
0.3.22+1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:12:
40: error: expected a type
- (instancetype)initWithMethodChannel:(FlutterMethodChannel*)methodChannel
                                       ^
   /Users/admin/Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/webview_flutter- 
   0.3.22+1/ios/Classes/JavaScriptChannelHandler.m:29:
   17: warning: unused variable 'arguments' [-Wunused-variable]
  NSDictionary* arguments = @{
                ^
  1 warning and 3 errors generated.
   note: Using new build system
   note: Building targets in parallel
  note: Planning build
  note: Constructing build description

  Encountered error while building for device.
```

y bueno tambien cuando abro el Runner en xcode me encuentro con esto:

[image: Error en xcode]

Ahora en las anteriores build que ejecute aveces me solia salir algunos error en el xcode pero lo solucionaba haciendo flutter clean en vscode y clean y rebuild en xcode pero esta vez no funciono para este caso y ahora siempre me sale este error.

```
  flutter doctor
 Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
 [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F101, locale en-US)

 [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.4.1)
 [✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.48.2)
[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Inclusive hice `flutter pub cache repair` y no funciono

Muchas gracias amigos por su ayuda.

Comment: entra a la carpeta de ios ,  cd ios/  y ejecuta  pod update , luego flutter clean e intenta de nuevo

Comment: Hola diegoveloper gracias por tu respuesta, hice todo lo que me dijiste entre al ios con cd ios luego pod update actualizo todo luego en vscode flutter clean y luego flutter build ios --release pero igual me sigue tirando el mismo error. Gracias diegoveloper

Comment: Puedes revisar tu archivo PodFile, que version de ios tiene en la primera linea? Lo q puedes hacer tambien es borrar ese archivo para que se vuelva a generar

Comment: Revise el PodFile en VsCode y tengo esto: platform :ios, '9.0'

Comment: Cambialo a 11.0  y prueba de nuevo

Comment: Pero esta comentado esa linea diegoveloper, igual lo cambio ? estando comentado? esta asi:  `# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'`

Comment: Descomentalo y actualizalo a 11.0

Comment: DiegoVeloper, te comento que no me funciono , me sigue tirando el mismo error :(.

Comment: hice el pod update, flutter clean , y flutter build.... y igual el mismo error

Comment: según yo veo el error es en el paquete webview_flutter, acabas de instalar esa extensión.